Conditionally exclude TransferRepresentation when importing
I have the following TransferRepresentation that, depending on the user settings imports a live photo or a static image:
public static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
    FileRepresentation(contentType: .livePhoto) { livePhoto in
        SentTransferredFile(livePhoto.url)
    } importing: { received in
        @SharedReader(.mediaEncoding) var mediaEncoding
        guard case .currentWithLivePhotos = mediaEncoding else {
            throw MyError.livePhotosExcludedBySettings
        }
        return try copyMedia(source: received.file)
    }
    FileRepresentation(contentType: .image) { image in
        SentTransferredFile(image.url)
    } importing: { received in
        return try copyMedia(source: received.file)
    }
}

Throwing an error to avoid the live photo being loaded is quite a hack, though. Is there a better way to conditionally exclude a contentType?
I cannot use an if statement:
//  Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'TransferRepresentationBuilder'
if case .currentWithLivePhotos = mediaEncoding {
    FileRepresentation(contentType: .livePhoto) { livePhoto in
        SentTransferredFile(livePhoto.url)
    } importing: { received in
        return try copyMedia(source: received.file)
    }
}

For exporting we could use exportingCondition. I cannot find an equivalent for importing.

What is this SharedReader? Is it something like an AppStorage?

Shared state from the Composable Architecture. Just a way to get the setting into the Transferable.
